# python code functions not displaying last column

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

my two functions show_info and show_filtered_info are not displaying the last column 'Notes' only shows first 7 of 8 columns.

I have tried many different options even chatgpt can't help.

please I am new to python and have tried my best to look for the answers I am very confused.

the spreadsheet has 8 columns but both show info functions only displays first 7 and misses last column

[sample data all columns show correctly apart from the last](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp0Hq.jpg)

[This is the out put I get I cannot make the box big enough to show any more columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggskv.jpg)

```
'''
This code demonstrates a simple information entry system using Tkinter.
The entered information is saved to an Excel file, and the user can also
view the information from the Excel file.

The code uses the following libraries:
- tkinter: For creating the GUI
- messagebox: For displaying error or success messages
- scrolledtext: For displaying the information in a scrollable text area
- openpyxl: For working with Excel files
- sys: For exiting the program
- tkcalendar: For displaying date entry fields
'''

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import sys
from tkcalendar import DateEntry



def validate_returned(event):
    input_string = entry_returned.get()
    if input_string and input_string.upper() not in ['Y', 'N']:
        entry_returned.delete(0, tk.END)
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter 'Y' or 'N'.")

def save_to_excel():
    # Get the information entered by the user
    first_name = entry_first_name.get()
    surname = entry_surname.get()
    ern = entry_ern.get()
    first_day_sick = entry_first_day_sick.get()
    last_day_sick = entry_last_day_sick.get()
    fit_note_expiry = entry_fit_note_expiry.get()
    returned = entry_returned.get()
    notes = entry_notes.get()

    try:
        # Load the existing Excel workbook
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')
        sheet = workbook.active
    except FileNotFoundError:
        # If the workbook doesn't exist, create a new one
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        sheet = workbook.active
        # Add headers to the sheet if it's empty
        if sheet.max_row == 0:
            sheet.append(["First Name", "Surname", "ERN", "FDS", "LDS", "FitN", "Ret", "Notes"])

    # Append the information to the Excel sheet
    sheet.append([first_name, surname, ern, first_day_sick, last_day_sick, fit_note_expiry, returned, notes])

    # Save the Excel file
    workbook.save('data.xlsx')
    messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Information saved to Excel file!")

    # Clear the entry fields
    entry_first_name.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_surname.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_ern.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_first_day_sick.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_last_day_sick.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_fit_note_expiry.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_returned.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_notes.delete(0, tk.END)

# Function to show a new window with filtered data
def show_filtered_data():
    # Load the Excel workbook
    try:
        workbook = load_workbook("data.xlsx")

        # Select the appropriate sheet
        current_sheet = workbook.active

        # Define the headers
        headers = ["First", "Sur", "ERN", "FDS", "LDS", "FitN", "Ret", "Notes"]

        # Filter rows where "Returned = n"
        filtered_data = []
        for row in current_sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            if row[6] == "n":
                filtered_data.append(row)

        # Create a new window for filtered data
        filtered_window = tk.Toplevel(window)
        filtered_window.title("Returned = n")
        filtered_window.geometry("1500x600")

        # Create a treeview widget to display the filtered data
        tree = ttk.Treeview(filtered_window, columns=headers, show="headings")
        
        # Set the column headers
        for header in headers:
            tree.heading(header, text=header)

        # Set the style to center-align the data
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("Treeview", cellanchor="center")

        # Set the column alignment to center
        for col in headers:
            tree.column(col, anchor="center")

        # Insert the filtered data into the treeview
        for row in filtered_data:
            tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row)

        tree.pack()

    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No data file found!")




def show_info():
    try:
        # Load the existing Excel workbook
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx')

        # Select the appropriate sheet
        current_sheet = workbook.active

        # Get the headers
        headers = ["First", "Sur", "ERN", "FDS", "LDS", "FitN", "Ret", "Notes"]

        # Create a new window to display the information
        info_window = tk.Toplevel()
        info_window.title("Information Display")

        # Create a treeview widget
        tree = ttk.Treeview(info_window, columns=headers, show="headings")

        # Set the column headers
        for header in headers:
            tree.heading(header, text=header)

        # Set the style to center align the data
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure("Treeview", cellanchor="center")

        # Set the column alignment to center
        for col in headers:
            tree.column(col, anchor="center")

        # Get the data from the sheet
        data = current_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True)

        # Insert the data into the treeview
        for row in data:
            tree.insert("", tk.END, values=row[:len(headers)])

        # Calculate the total width required by all columns
        total_width = sum(tree.column(col, option="width") for col in headers)

        # Set the width of the information window to accommodate all columns
        info_window.geometry(f"{total_width+30}x600")

        # Create a horizontal scrollbar
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(info_window, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)

        # Configure the scrollbar to scroll horizontally with the treeview
        tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # Pack the treeview and scrollbar
        tree.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        scrollbar.pack(fill="x")

    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No data file found!")




def close_program():
    sys.exit()

# Create the main application window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Information Entry")
window.geometry("400x600")

# Create labels and entry fields
label_first_name = tk.Label(window, text="First Name:")
label_first_name.pack()
entry_first_name = tk.Entry(window)
entry_first_name.pack()

label_surname = tk.Label(window, text="Surname:")
label_surname.pack()
entry_surname = tk.Entry(window)
entry_surname.pack()

label_ern = tk.Label(window, text="ERN:")
label_ern.pack()
entry_ern = tk.Entry(window)
entry_ern.pack()

label_first_day_sick = tk.Label(window, text="First Day Sick:")
label_first_day_sick.pack()
entry_first_day_sick = DateEntry(window)
#entry_first_day_sick = tk.Entry(window)
entry_first_day_sick.pack()

label_last_day_sick = tk.Label(window, text="Last Day Sick:")
label_last_day_sick.pack()
entry_last_day_sick = DateEntry(window)
#entry_last_day_sick = tk.Entry(window)
entry_last_day_sick.pack()

label_fit_note_expiry = tk.Label(window, text="Fit Note Expiry:")
label_fit_note_expiry.pack()
entry_fit_note_expiry = DateEntry(window)
#entry_fit_note_expiry = tk.Entry(window)
entry_fit_note_expiry.pack()

label_returned = tk.Label(window, text="Returned Y/N:")
label_returned.pack()
entry_returned = tk.Entry(window)
entry_returned.pack()
entry_returned.bind("<KeyRelease>", validate_returned)

label_notes = tk.Label(window, text="Notes:")
label_notes.pack()
entry_notes = tk.Entry(window)
entry_notes.pack()

# Create a button to save the information to Excel
button_save = tk.Button(window, text="Save to Excel", command=save_to_excel)
button_save.pack()

# Create a button to display the information
button_show = tk.Button(window, text="Show Info", command=show_info)
button_show.pack()

button_close = tk.Button(window, text="Close", command=close_program)
button_close.pack()

button_filter = tk.Button(window, text="Show Filtered Data", command=show_filtered_data)
button_filter.pack()

# Start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with my sample Excel file.  Both functions show the values of "Notes" column in the treeview.  It is better to show some sample data in your "data.xlsx" file.

Comment: added sample data, the first 7 columns and headers all work but cannot get last column to show with header and column data

Comment: I have no problem using your sample data.

Comment: strange I have included a screen shot of my out put I can only see 7 of the 8 columns and cannot make the box any bigger

Comment: May be the window is not wide enough to show all the columns.  Try setting the column width to smaller value.

Comment: Thank you that worked
*********************************
 # Set the column alignment to center
        for col in headers:
            tree.column(col, anchor="center", width=tree.column(col, option="width") - 30)

Comment: sorry how do I sent questioned to solved?

Comment: You can simply delete the question.